# x>1 APPs running on the same time on Android

Tags: android

At #GDDDE i was sitting in a ignite talk by @creaseapp - a tiling window manager for Android. And since then I do not get the following question out of my head: "how to let x>1 APPs run on the same time" - @creaseapp solves the problem by just using WebAPPs - this is a easy to implement and working solution, but with native APP support we could have so much more use-cases.

Comment: "How to let x>1 APPs run on the same time"? What excatly do you want to do? Starting ONE SINGLE app multiple times?

Comment: I attended the same session, so I know what ligi is talking about. Basically, what they want to achieve is to run multiple apps and show their output on one screen. For example, running 2 apps side by side - as it would be possible on any regular operating systems (e.g., text editor in one window, browser in another, but shown side by side). Is that possible? From what I know, this would require modifications to the Android system itself.

Comment: Yep. I also dont know any possibility to solve this. I think Android is not designed for this use case, and honestly, I dont see any use-case for this. In my opinion this is useless and uninteressting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that the time is now ripe:

https://github.com/Onskreen/cornerstone

thanks to Ronan Schwarz for the hint on G+

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, what they want to achieve is to run multiple apps and show their output on one screen. For example, running 2 apps side by side - as it would be possible on any regular operating systems (e.g., text editor in one window, browser in another, but shown side by side). Is that possible?

No.

> From what I know, this would require modifications to the Android system itself.

Substantial modifications, yes. This has been asked repeatedly over the years, and the answer has always been that this would be a Herculean task to add. Note that more operating systems are moving towards one-app-at-a-time models (OS X Lion, Ubuntu Unity).